# Прическа "хвост"

Tags: пунктуация

Есть такая прическа - хвост. Когда волосы просто собраны в пучок и затянуты резинкой. Еще его называют "конский хвост".
Но я вижу это название то в кавычках, то без. А как все-таки правильно? Просто, если написать без кавычек, например, "У нее был длинный хвост", это выйдет, мягко скажем, смешно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё зависит от содержания текста и его стиля.

Эту прическу называют "конский хвост". Здесь кавычки поставлены верно, они позволяют использовать начальную форму  названия.

Конским хвостом принято называть прическу, которая делается на длинных волосах. Здесь возможны оба варианта, но в данном случае кавычки не поставлены, так как дается определение прически, а название при этом считается общепринятым.

Длинные гладкие волосы на ночь завяжите в тугой "конский хвост". Это специальная литература, где название оформлено в виде условного термина, поэтому ставятся кавычки.

В художественном тексте лучше сказать так: волосы были собраны в длинный хвост.